sd card becomes unrecognisable after large data transfers
i have a sandisk 64 gb sd card, recently it has been acting a bit weird. whenever i plug the sd card into my phone with around 20 gbs of data, my phone recognises it as corrupt while i can still use it on my laptop. i tried transferring data while the sd card is readable on my phone, but if i restart my phone, it recognises it as corrupt. so far its done this on only exfat format sd cards, and i wish to use the sd card for extended use, having to backup files every restart is annoying. do i have to go with fat32 format? some of my files are over 4 gigabyte since i compress them often, but if theres no other answer, im willing to use it. any help is appreciated, thank you.

What phone phone do you use (manufacture, model, Android version). Official ExFAT support for Android pretty young, but a lot of manufacturer added it earlier, however often with bugs. I would recommend to test the SD-card with FAT and see if this helps. When the phone recognized the card as corrupt, can your computer still read it?

@Robert sorry for my late reply, but I'm using an infinix note 10 pro, with android 11. Yes, the card is readable on my pc, i ran a bad sector check, and it came out clean. The weird thing is my phone will not recognize it once it goes past 10 gigabytes in filled storage. This happens on reinsertion, if i fill it while its mounted, no issues. I restart, bam, phone stops recognizing it. Only happened to me on exfats
